# SSH key not found on remote machine

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, ssh-keygen

I have the following setup: I have my laptop A, a computer B, and a remote machine C. C can only be accessed from B via ssh, B may be accessed via ssh from A or used directly. A is always used directly.

I managed to setup the ssh keys in such a way, that I don't need to enter my password when connecting from A to B, or from B to C.

But when I connect from A to B, and then try to ssh to C, I still have to enter my password - how can I use the key that's obviously available on B, as I'm able to use it if I log in to B directly?

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site! Are you connecting to C _from_ B or _from_ A? If you `ssh` into B first, C should have the public key of **B** installed.

Comment: @MrShunz I'm first connecting to B, and once I'm on B, I try to connect to C. If I login on B directly (no ssh, directly on the computer), I can then ssh to C without needing to enter a password. So I guess the key of B is already installed on C?

Comment: Why can you not connect from A to C, and bypass B all together?

Comment: @Christopher are you using the _same_ user when you login from `ssh` and directly from the computer?

Comment: @eyoung100 C is a cluster, B a regular computer. I need to run scripts on B that monitor the progress of programs on C (also, C is just not accessible from anything but B, that's the way the network is set up, I can't change that)

Comment: @MrShunz yes, I am

Comment: When SSHing from B to C under both methods use the `-v` (or `-vv`) flags to give more verbose output, compare these looking for differences, in particular any information about keys that are being passed.  This should help you determine whether a key is actually being passed when you go A > B > C.  Do you use anything like [keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) to manage your SSH keys? If not it may be that when you SSH A > B your key is not loaded.

Comment: @slackline Thanks, that was very helpful! I discovered that the key wasn't found and could fix the problem. I'm curious about why the key was found when I logged in to B directly. The next time I can access B physically, I'll check that.

Answer (score 1):

When SSHing from A trough B to C, using the `ssh -vv REMOTE` revealed that the key on B wasn't found. The output ended with

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /u/USER/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /u/USER/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /u/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Additionally, I noticed that I didn't name the private key `id_dsa` or `id_rsa` but `id_rsa_cluster`. I fixed this using

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_cluster
```

Now, the key is found and I can login without entering my password.

I'm currently unable to physically access B, so I can't check why the key was found when I logged in to B directly. But once I can, I'll add this.

Comment: Great, glad to be of assistance, sounds like its an issue with `ssh-agent` not being sourced on remote login from A to B and the fix you mention should be added to `~/bashrc`  so that it happens each time you login.

Answer (score 0):

The sshd_config option `AllowAgentForwarding` needs to be enabled on B. The SSH client might also need agent forwarding enabled.